# How pass the string to list dynamically

Tags: python, list

My code is below

- I am passing doc and specia not foo' dynamically to `search_body`
- after `and` string it will come in should
- after `not` string it will come in must_not

```
search_string = 'doc and specia not foo'
search_terms = search_string.split()
search_body = {
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [],
            "should": [],
            "must_not": []
        }
    }
}

# Process each search term
for i, term in enumerate(search_terms):
    if term.lower() == "and" or term.lower() == "or":
        continue  # Skip the "and" and "or" keywords

    # Get the next search term if it exists
    if i < len(search_terms) - 1:
        next_term = search_terms[i + 1]

        if next_term.lower() == "not":
            # Handle "not" operator
            search_body['query']['bool']['must_not'].append({"match": {"your_field_name": term}})
        else:
            # Handle other terms
            operator = "must"
            if term.lower() == "or":
                operator = "should"

            search_body['query']['bool'][operator].append({"match": {"your_field_name": next_term}})
        continue

    # Handle the last search term
    search_body['query']['bool']['must'].append({"match": {"your_field_name": term}})

print(search_body)
```

My out is. >>

```
{
  'query': {
    'bool': {
      'must': [
        {
          'match': {
            'your_field_name': 'and'
          }
        },
        {
          'match': {
            'your_field_name': 'foo'
          }
        }
      ],
      'should': [
        
      ],
      'must_not': [
        {
          'match': {
            'your_field_name': 'specia'
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

My expected is >>

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {"match": {"your_field_name": "doc"}}
            ],
            "should": [
                {"match": {"your_field_name": "specia"}}
            ],
            "must_not": [
                {"match": {"your_field_name": "foo"}}
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You say "string it will come in should", but it looks like you are testing for "or". What's the correct behavior after "or"? Is it the same as "and"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your description is not detailed enough, so I can only provide a solution based on my understanding.

```
search_string = 'doc and specia not foo'
search_terms = search_string.strip().split()
search_body = {
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [],
            "should": [],
            "must_not": []
        }
    }
}

first_flag = True
# Process each search term
for i, term in enumerate(search_terms):
    if term.lower() not in ["and", "not", "or"]:
        continue  # Skip the "and" and "or" keywords

    if first_flag:
        search_body['query']['bool']['must'].append({"match": {"your_field_name": search_terms[i-1]}})
        first_flag = False
    # Get the next search term if it exists
    if i < len(search_terms) - 1:
        next_term = search_terms[i + 1]
        if term.lower() == "not":
            # Handle "not" operator
            search_body['query']['bool']['must_not'].append({"match": {"your_field_name": next_term}})
        else:
            # Handle other terms
            operator = "must"
            if term.lower() in ["and", "or"]:
                operator = "should"
            search_body['query']['bool'][operator].append({"match": {"your_field_name": next_term}})

print(search_body)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should handle the case if the last term isn't an operator.

```
# If the next term doesn't exist, it means the current term is the last term
# Add it as a "must" condition
search_body['query']['bool']['must'].append({"match": {"your_field_name": term}})
```

If the last term is not an operator (`and` or `or`) it should be added as `must` to the `search_body`.

Comment: I tried that it did not help, edited the question  also